# How to notify all Threads after receiving input

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I'm currently developing something where I have a server waiting for connections and once a connection is established, a Thread is created to handle the communication between the Server and the Client. All this communication is String based, making use of InputStreamReaders and OutputStreamReaders and what I need to do at the moment is to be able to send a message to every connected Client, through their own ServerThread. A simple view of how things are written is:

```
public final static int SERVER_PORT = 12345;   
private static int numThreads=0;

public void Server() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Server.SERVER_PORT);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            numThreads++;
            new ServerThread(socket, numThreads).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `numThreads` is used mainly for printing specific information to the client. On the `ServerThread` I would have:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        String command=null;
        try{
            command = readString(); //method that reads input from Client
            //Do actions based on command
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.getMessage();                    
        }
    }
    //Close streams and socket
}
```

The content of the methods shown might have some typos since there's a lot more on them at the moment, but should help visualize the problem.

To simplify the Client side, lets just imagine that there's a Client, that connects to the Server and sends commands/messages to our `ServerThread`.

Every time a Client is connected to the Server, a new `ServerThread` is created, which will continuously wait for the Client to send a `command`. If this `command` corresponds to, e.g., "send", I need to send a message to every Client connected to the Server.

How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide an idea, which can be solved by event monitoring (Observer Pattern). 
 Can separate publishers into a separate class.

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

  // Used for event subscription (CopyOnWriteArrayList is not the best implementation, please adjust
  // according to project needs)
  private static final List<ServerThread> LISTENERS = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

  public ServerThread(Socket socket, int num) {
    // do something ...
    LISTENERS.add(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      String command = null;
      try {
        command = readString(); // method that reads input from Client
        // Do actions based on command
        if ("send".equals(command)) {
          ServerThread.publish(new SendEvent(command));
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    // Close streams and socket
  }

  private String readString() {
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * event publishing method
   *
   * @param event
   */
  public static void publish(SendEvent event) {
    LISTENERS.forEach(listener -> listener.listen(event));
  }

  /**
   * Event processing method
   *
   * @param event
   */
  public void listen(SendEvent event) {
    // to something ...
  }
}
```